# How to drop columns from a dataframe that contain specific values in any row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

In a pandas dataframe, I need to find columns that contain a zero in any row, and drop that whole column.

For example, if my dataframe looks like this:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1
1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
```

I need to drop columns A, B, D, and F.  I know how to drop the columns, but identifying the ones with zeros programmatically is eluding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1], 'B': [1, 0, 1]})
for col in df.columns:
    if 0 in df[col].tolist():
        df = df.drop(columns=col)
df
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.loc` to slice the dataframe and perform boolean indexation on the columns, checking which have [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) `0` in them:

```
df.loc[:,~(df==0).any()]

   C  E  G  H
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
```

Or equivalently you can do:

```
df.loc[:,(df!=0).all()]
```

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda x: x if x == 1 else np.nan).dropna(axis=1)` is easier to read and about half the time with timeit.

Comment: Try with a larger dataframe @fredrik  Keep in mind that apply and applymap are just python level loops, which will make your solution scale much worse for larger dataframes